# UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'command' where it is not associated with a value

Tags: python, voice

If I don't give this program a voice command within aprox 3 seconds after "listeng..." is being prompted, I get the "UnboundLocalError" mentioned in the title.

Looking for any advice on how to get the program to wait for my next voice command without shutting down. Sorry if stupid question, this is my first ever program.

Program below:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import datetime
import wikipedia
import pyjokes

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
engine.setProperty("voice", voices[0].id)


def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("listening...")
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            if "computer" in command:
                command = command.replace("computer", "")
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command


def run_alexa():
    command = take_command()
    print(command)

    if "play" in command:
        song = command.replace("play", "")
        talk("playing" + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)

    elif "time" in command:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M %p")
        talk("the current time is " + time)

    elif "tell me about" in command:
        person = command.replace("tell me about", "")
        info = wikipedia.summary(person, 1)
        talk(info)

    elif "your favourite artist" in command:
        talk("Mr worldwide aka pitbull")

    elif "joke" in command:
        talk(pyjokes.get_joke())

    else:
        talk("what are you talking about willis")


while True:
    run_alexa()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Alex/Documents/vscode/Virtual assistant/main.py", line 90, in <module>
    run_alexa()
  File "/Users/Alex/Documents/vscode/Virtual assistant/main.py", line 32, in run_alexa
    command = take_command()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Alex/Documents/vscode/Virtual assistant/main.py", line 29, in take_command
    return command
           ^^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'command' where it is not associated with a value
```

Comment: Could you please add the full traceback to your question - it will help you get more useful answers to your question!

Comment: @PirateNinjas Alright, traceback is added, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that an exception happens somewhere in `take_command()`, and no value gets associated with `command`, so it can't be returned.

Never, ever use a bare `try: ... except: pass`, as as you've noticed, you can then never tell what's actually going wrong.

Change that function to something like

```
def take_command():
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("listening...")
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
        if command and "computer" in command:
            command = command.replace("computer", "")
            return command
    return None
```

to begin with, and debug from there (it's likely that that function will now raise an exception).

Answer (score 0):

In your "take_command" def, you have to assign a value to the command var wether it receives a command or not.

```
Ex: 

def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            if 'computer' in command:
                command = command.replace('computer', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        command = ''
    return command
```

notice how if no command is given then i pass it an empty value with the ''.
by just entering pass it passes assigning the var which is what cause it to be referenced before assignment.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue might be with your `take_command` function.

```
def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("listening...")
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            if "computer" in command:
                command = command.replace("computer", "")
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command
```

Specifically, your return statement is the immediate problem. You return `command`, but if your `try` block raised an exception before `command` is set, you `pass` in the `except` clause. This means two things:

1. Your try block has a problem with it (can't say for sure what that is right now)
2. Your code can lead to this error because command can end up unset.

To fix 2, you could change your except to set command, like:

```
def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("listening...")
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            if "computer" in command:
                command = command.replace("computer", "")
                print(command)
    except:
        command = None
    return command
```

But I would see what happens if you remove the naked except clause and try and improve there:

```
def take_command():
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("listening...")
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
        if "computer" in command:
            command = command.replace("computer", "")
            print(command)

    return command
```

This will mean errors that occur are thrown unhandled, but I think maybe that is more useful in your usecase.

Answer (score -3):

Try updating your Python version and Python libraries to the latest version. If that doesn't work, try initiating the command variable, just after the try text `def take_command(): try: command = "" with sr.Microphone() as source: print('listening...') voice = listener.listen(source) command = listener.recognize_google(voice) if 'computer' in command: command = command.replace('computer', '') print(command) except: pass return command`
Try this and see what happens, and if the issue is still not solved, then let me know, I will help you solve it.
Hope this helps.